# MPMoviePlayerController shows blank white screen before launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have an MPMoviePlayerController that I am presenting modally. The video loads fine, however just before the video is launched the screen turns white until it has loaded. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mySTVideo.video_url]];

[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayerViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should be using this for display the movies:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

Second, to change the moviePlayerViewController background you can use:

```
moviePlayerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

So when the video is launched the background color will be black.

Hope its helps...

Answer (score 9):

Also, you should make sure to set the `movieSourceType` on your `MPMoviePlayercontroller` (which you can access via `moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer`).

If you don't set this property, it defaults to `MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown`, and the player won't show controls until the request has returned (which can take a while on [WWAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_WAN)).