# white screen before MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

i am streaming a video from a server, it works perfectly using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. 
but the problem is that if the size of the video is too big a white screen will show before the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` connects and starts playing the video.
 this is annoying, and i have no clue how to fix it.
 this is the code i am using to play the video:

```
NSString *videoURLString = @"http://serverAdress/test/videotest/starwars.mp4";
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerView = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 moviePlayerView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Resource: [MPMoviePlayerController shows blank white screen before launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128558/mpmovieplayercontroller-shows-blank-white-screen-before-launch)

Comment: actually the real solution was the post by "Michael Grinich" in the link you provided not the actual answer to that question. ty....